# not able to create a file in openshift gives Permission denied

Tags: docker, openshift

I have below dockerfile and using I have created docker image which is used in my openshift deployment but the logs of the pod shows error

```
/bin/sh: can't create /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf: Permission denied
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM abc/abc-ui-base:latest AS build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN set -ex && apk --update add ruby
COPY --from=build /root/build/nginx.docker.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/fs.template
COPY --from=build /root/dist /public

RUN chmod go+w /var/cache/nginx
RUN chmod -R 777 /etc/nginx

CMD erb /etc/nginx/conf.d/fs.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf; cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf; nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below line in the docker file and issue was resolved. So the erb command worked

```
RUN chmod 777 /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```